# jQuery newsitems hide and collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am using a nice script to hide and show several divs

```
// Catch all clicks on a link with the class 'link'
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    // Stop the link being followed:
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the div to be shown:
    var content = $(this).attr('rel');
    // Remove any active classes:
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    // Add the 'active' class to this link:
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // Hide all the content:
    $('.content').hide();
    // Show the requested content:
    $('#' + content).show();
});
```

This works great on a single div with several items I like to hide.

But I use a template the retrieves news items and I like to make this work on all the divs induvidual. Also hide the second div by default.

```
<div class="content" id="div[[+idx]]-1">
    <p>Show content by default</p>
    <a class="link-[[+idx]]" href="#" rel="div[[+idx]]-2">
        Link to show div id="div[[+idx]]-2" and hide id="div[[+idx]]-1"
    </a>
</div>
<div class="content hide" id="div[[+idx]]-2">
    <p>Hide content by default</p>
    <a class="link-[[+idx]]" href="#" rel="div[[+idx]]-1">
        Link to show div id="div[[+idx]]-1" and hide div id="div[[+idx]]-2"
    </a>
</div>
```

Problem is I use this template for every iteration and the script does not support an undefined number of items and closes all my other divs. As does the second div does not hide on default.

I changed the link to link1 and then you get the follwoing unwanted bahavior:
http://jsfiddle.net/Vh7HR/8/

if I leave out the 1 it does nothing

Comment: see my answer, you're currently going to tell ***EVERY*** Element with the class *"content"* to hide. If you want just the child of the element, you need to select it via parent()
**EDIT: just realized that your links are actually children of the div that you want to hide, so what you actually want is parent selector**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make use of .parent()

```
// Catch all clicks on a link with the class 'link'
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    // Stop the link being followed:
    e.preventDefault();
    // Get the div to be shown:
    var content = $(this).attr('rel');
    // Remove any active classes:
    $('.active').removeClass('active');
    // Add the 'active' class to this link:
    $(this).addClass('active');
    // Hide all the content:
    $(this).parent('.content').hide();
    // Show the requested content:
    $('#' + content).show();
});
```

Comment: Cool thanks this is great adjusted it on JSFiddle. Now I only need to get the second div to be hidden by default.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use delegation if you are adding new `.link` dynamically.

By using [**.on()**](http://api.jquery.com/on/) you can listen for a click on document (or another element that is ancestor to `.link` and is present when the click handler is attached) and when the click is fired it will look for `.link`.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(e) {
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use the on method provided by jquery to handle click events, the classic click method not works with elements that you create after rendering the DOM.

```
$( "your-selector" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( "Hello world!");
});
```